# suspension problem on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, suspend

I have a dual booted laptop with windows 7 home.
I was able to perform suspension on my previous version of ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but eversince I have upgraded to **16.04 LTS**, I am not able to suspend my laptop, properly.
That is, after clicking on "**suspend**" button the *screen goes black*, but when i want to get back again, it just wont start.Although the power and battery indication light starts blinking again, the screen still remains black .
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by upgrading to kernel 4.5

**64Bit**

```
wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc1-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500rc1_4.5.0-040500rc1.201601241731_all.deb"

wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc1-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500rc1-generic_4.5.0-040500rc1.201601241731_amd64.deb"

wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc1-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500rc1-generic_4.5.0-040500rc1.201601241731_amd64.deb"

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**32Bit**

```
wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc1-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500rc1_4.5.0-040500rc1.201601241731_all.deb"

wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc1-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500rc1-generic_4.5.0-040500rc1.201601241731_i386.deb"

wget "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-rc1-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500rc1-generic_4.5.0-040500rc1.201601241731_i386.deb"

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Here is kernel 4.6

**64Bit:**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**32Bit**:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_i386.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: thanks a lot Inforcer25 ! kernel 4.5 for 32 bit worked for me!

Comment: now a new problem has arised after updating my kernel :( I am **not**  able to boot my ubuntu, It shows a balck screen with this written on it:  _end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found_

Comment: This was probably caused by fixes and features backported from newer kernels.

In GRUB menu, select Advanced options for Ubuntu, choose the last kernel that worked (not recovery mode).

Comment: Ok. Done. Shall I uninstall the newer kernel version or is there a way I can fix the issue with version 4.5

Comment: Look at my answere. I updated so that there is kernel 4.6 now. try using kernel 4.6